# How to fix a typescript reference error in Google Cloud Build

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, vuejs3, google-cloud-build, monorepo

I have a typescript monorepo where a vue 3 app imports (custom) types and config constants from ad hoc modules/packages scoped to the app, i.e: `@myapp/types` or `@myapp/config`. These packages are private and not imported from the npm registry.
I have no issues importing, building or serving the app locally. However, in Cloud Build, my builds consistently fails with the the following message:

[image: cloud build error typescript config]

Here are the tsconfig.json files from the "importer" repo, i.e my Vue app consuming the types and also going through the pipeline:

tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "files": [],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.vite-config.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.vitest.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "../../packages/types/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "../../packages/config/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```js
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@myapp/config": ["../../packages/config"],
      "@myapp/types": ["../../packages/types"]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the structure of the monorepo:

- root (tsconfig.base.json)

  - apps

    - ui  <== consumer (tsconfig.app.json + tsconfig.json)
  - packages

    - types   <= custom types (tsconfig.json)
    - config   <= custom types

As a FYI here is the tsconfig.json available in the types module:

```js
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ES6",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true
  },
  "files": ["index.ts"],
  "display": "Types"
}
```

And here is the tsconfig.base.json located at the root of the repo:

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "@myapp/types": ["./packages/types"],
      "@myapp/config": ["./packages/config"],
      "@myapp/ui": ["./packages/ui"],
      "@myapp/ui-b2b": ["./apps/ui-b2b/src"],
      "@myapp/ui-partners": ["./apps/ui-patners/src"],
      "@myapp/api": ["./apps/api/src"]
    }
  }
}
```

And finally my cloudbuild yaml file:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: node:16
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ["install"]
  - name: node:16
    dir: "apps/ui-b2b"
    entrypoint: npm
    env:
      - "DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=$_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
      - "VITE_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=$_VITE_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY"
      - "VITE_DYNAMIC_LINKS_DOMAIN=$_VITE_DYNAMIC_LINKS_DOMAIN"
      - "VITE_API_URL=$_VITE_API_URL"
      - "VITE_DISPOSABLE_API_KEY=$_VITE_DISPOSABLE_API_KEY"
      - "VITE_GCP_AUTH_TENANT_ID=$_VITE_GCP_AUTH_TENANT_ID"
      - "VITE_FIREBASE_CONFIG=$_VITE_FIREBASE_CONFIG"
      - "VITE_BASE_DOMAIN=$_VITE_BASE_DOMAIN"
      - "VITE_LOCAL=$_VITE_LOCAL"
      - "VITE_STRIPE_ALLOW_PROMOTION_CODES=$_VITE_STRIPE_ALLOW_PROMOTION_CODES"
      - "VITE_TOAST_DURATION=$_VITE_TOAST_DURATION"
      - "VITE_SEARCH_API_KEY=$_VITE_SEARCH_API_KEY"
      - "VITE_SEARCH_API_HOST=$_VITE_SEARCH_API_HOST"
      - "VITE_SEARCH_API_PORT=$_VITE_SEARCH_API_PORT"
      - "VITE_SEARCH_API_PROTOCOL=$_VITE_SEARCH_API_PROTOCOL"
    args: ["run", "build:development"]
  - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: "bash"
    dir: "apps/ui-b2b"
    args:
      [
        "-c",
        "gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1600 && gcloud app deploy",
      ]
timeout: "1600s"
```

I have tried several things such as updating the paths, removing the references etc. but all leads to other or new errors.

Any idea as to why this could be happening or how to fix that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you run `npm run build:development` on your local machine to see if it works? In general, you need to keep your gcloud environment to be the same as your local environment. It included env variables, the nodejs version, and the build script. Double-check your variables by printing them out in the build process

Comment: Hi @Duannx, I did and then served the app locally. Everything runs perfectly there.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the typescript error was the tree masking the forest.
Still not sure ***why*** this is happening but here is ***what*** is happening.

It seems that when deploying to app engine with the `gcloud app deploy` command, app engine tries to build the application by default before the actual deployment.
So I ended up with the following:

- step 1: npm i
- step 2: npm build for dev
- step 3: deploy (combined with a default npm build before deployment)

And my guess is that in step 3, the other TS modules / packages the app was reliant on have been discarded by the pipeline as the app had already been built.

I therefore muted the default build behaviour of app engine by adding `"gcp-build": ""` to my `package.json`, as specified here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#npm_build_script

[image: app engine custom build]

Builds and deployments are now fine.